# Chrome extension background fail?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I've been trying to make an extension on google chrome but it keeps failing at background worker.

Here's the error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kau0K.png)

Here's my background.js code:

```
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  console.log("Connected .....");
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
       console.log("message recieved" + msg);
       port.postMessage("Hi Popup.js");
  });
})
```

Here's popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input placeholder="Button name" id="bName"></input>
    <input placeholder="Button URL" id="urlName"></input>
    <hr>
    <button id="addbutton">Add button</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's script.js:

```
var port = chrome.extension.connect({
    name: "Sample Communication"
});
port.postMessage("Hi BackGround");
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    console.log("message recieved" + msg);
});
```

Comment: Try `manifest_version: 2` check if there are any error in code

Comment: @p2pdops tried it but then got `'action' requires manifest version of at least 3.` and `'scripting' requires manifest version of at least 3.`.

Comment: You're using **ancient** methods: `chrome.extension` in MV3 doesn't contain `connect` and `onConnect` anymore. Use `chrome.runtime` instead.

Comment: So how would the full code look like ? @wOxxOm

Comment: Replace all `chrome.extension` with `chrome.runtime`.

Answer (score 0):

> Replace all `chrome.extension` with `chrome.runtime`. - [xOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom)